# I got an error message about some Neon code

Tags: android, arm, neon

To learn ARM Neon on Android, I tried to run a sample code.

But I got an error message.

```
 uint16_t in[8] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
 uint16_t out[8];
 r = vld1q_u16(&in[0]);
 **vst1q_u16(&out[0], r);** <-- Here comes an error message
```

> the error message is Invalid Arguments

I don't understand why the problem was.

`vld1q_u16` works correctly and the value of `r` is also correct.

but `vst1q_u16` doesn't work.

Comment: Please include the full error message (copy and paste it to your question using the [edit] link above).

Comment: make sure **r** is declared correctly as **uint16x8_t r**. Your snippet compiles for me with gradle experimental plugin 0.2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
r = vld1q_u16(in);
vst1q_u16(out, r);
```

SIMD engines like NEON read memory contents backwards by default so giving it address of array element 0 is bad idea.